# Java null pointer exception on using simple Intent Extra

Tags: java, android, android-intent

When I try to send some text over to the next `Activity` the program crashes saying "null pointer exception unable to start activity" but without using `Intent Extra` the `Intent` works fine.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
EditText et;

public final static String KEY="com.example.myprotrial";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(KEY, et.getText().toString());
    startActivity(i);
}

}
```

**MyActivity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String a = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(a);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

**LogCat**

```
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myprotrial/com.example.myprotrial.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at com.example.myprotrial.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:18)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
12-09 13:58:33.115: E/AndroidRuntime(1588):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You are missing the most important parts of your locat. Please edit and post all of it

Comment: I'm guessing your TextView in MyActivity is null since when you removed your extra and it was "working" you never tried to access your TextView 'tv'

Comment: a/ `need help ASAP` is pointless. b/ start by **reading** your stacktrace, the issue is in it.

Comment: Try adding a log statement that prints `et.getText().toString()` in your onClick method. I agree with @dymmeh that your EditText probably does not contain anything.

Comment: Look at my answer of yours yesterday. Dymmeh is probably right and its the same type of deal as your last problem. In my previous answer of yours, I showed how I knew what the problem is. Go over that again because its very important that you can do preliminary debugging yourself if you want to be a developer.

Comment: And what is line 18 in `MyActivity.java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your LogCat doesn't tell on which line the NPE occurs.

From your code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String a = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.KEY);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(a);
}
```

The if the NPE is occurring on `intent.getStringExtra` then your intent is null.  If it's on `tv.setText(a)` then most likely the `activity_my` layout doesn't have `textView1` in it.  Step through it in the debugger and watch the instance variables.

Comment: "The problem is that your LogCat doesn't tell on which line the NPE occurs." Yes it does.

Comment: @DShaw i didnt check my MyActivity layout...it was missing the id for the textview...AND is it possible for the widgets of one activities layout to be used by another activity?

Comment: @new_jerry You can include one layout within another layout using the  <include> tag.  See here:  http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include  Remember that whenever you do findViewById() it has to resolve to a View that exists in the layout that you have inflated (in this case, in setContentView() above it).